# How can I start Chrome in normal desktop mode on Windows 8.1?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, microsoft-surface-pro

I was trying to get a webapp to run in fullscreen on a Surface Pro and started Google Chrome in "Windows 8 Mode". It didn't work right, so I decided to first install all pending updates.

Now, after installing all updates, Chrome opens like this:

[image: a very broken Chrome]

How can I get it back to start in normal desktop mode, or, alternatively, make it usable in the current mode?

Comment: You may have to reset the Chrome profile: Close all Chrome windows -> Go to **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\** -> Rename "Default" to "Default_BACKUP" -> Re-open Chrome and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @BigChris Same thing happens even after doing that.

Comment: Do "Alt + F" (whilst Chrome has focus) - this should bring the menu up for Chrome -> Click "Relaunch Chrome on the Desktop" from the menu?

Comment: Did you filter out information or do you actually have a black space on your screen? There is an option in the main menu to relaunch browser in desired mode.  I can't tell if the main menu is even an option, if not, try the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @BigChris Alt+F does nothing

Comment: @Ramhound That part of the screen is actually black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties(chrome application properties) > Compatibility > Disable display scaling on high DPI settings 
Then launch chrome

If it is launched properly, then click on Chrome's [hamburger button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM1dg.png) at the top right edge to open Chrome's menu panel. Next, click on "Relaunch Chrome on the desktop".

[image: hamburger button]

Comment: Checking the compatibility option allowed me to see the full application window again and I could relaunch through the hamburger button. Cheers

Comment: can't we just call it the menu button or the very least the `big mac` button :-)

Comment: Can you please show screenshots how to disable scaling? I am not able to find these settings. Thanks

Comment: @zarpio right click on the chrome icon on your taskbar, right click again on the Google Chrome option (3rd from the bottom I had in my case) to get the menu with Properties option